# Crystal 2008: Suppress record with multiple criteria

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal report looks like this:

```
No.|  Name   |    Test -  |   Date  
1  --| Fido   - |   yes   --  |  1/2/2010  
2  --| Rover   |   no ---   |  1/2/2010  
3  --| Fido   - |   yes  -- |  1/2/2010  
4  --| Fido   - |   yes -- |  1/8/2010  
5  --| Rover   |   no  ---  |  1/8/2010
```

There are lots of observations with much duplication.  Currently report suppresses records if duplicate in first column.  Only records 1 and 2 would show up.

I need to be able to suppress records where both columns 1 and 3 are the same regardless of what is in column 2.  In this case records 1,2,4,5 would all show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. try below way.

Create an array with the values first, For that purpose concatenate the required fields and create an array and select only those that are unique.

create a formula `@finalvalues`

```
Global Stringvar array mylist;

if Name&ToText(Date) in mylist
Then
1
else 
mylist:=mylist+Name&ToText(Date);
0;
```

Now go to the supress part of the section where fields are placed and write below code.

```
if {@finalvalues}=1
then true
else false
```